# Userscript works in Tampermonkey on Chrome but not in Greasemonkey on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have been using a userscript in Greasemonkey on Firefox and Tampermonkey on Chrome for over a year and a half now. It adds a scroll to top button on every webpage. I tried adding another site to include in Greasemonkey but then it seemed to have broken it. Now, the scroll to top button doesn't show up on any site in Firefox but the exact same userscript has no issues working in Chrome on Tampermonkey. I did not create this script. I got it from Userscripts.org back before it went down. Below is the script. Does anyone know what might need to be changed in the script to make it compatible with Greasemonkey again?

I'm using Firefox 41.0 for xUbuntu and Greasemonkey 3.4.1.
My Chrome is 45.0.2454.101 and Tampermonkey 3.11.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Scroll To Top Button
// @version        v1.3.2
// @include        http://*
// @include        https://*
// ==/UserScript==
(function(global) {
if(global !== window) return;

function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function bind(context, name) {
    return function() {
        return context[name].apply(context, arguments);
    }
}

global.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, false);

function scrollHandler() {
    !scroll.isScrolling && ((scroll.getScrollY() > 0) ? scroll.showBtn() : scroll.hideBtn());
}

var scroll = {
    __scrollY : 0,
    isScrolling : false,  //is scrolling
    imgBtn : null,
    isBtnShow : false,
    pageHeight : 0,
    speed : 0.75,
    init : function() {
        var document = global.document,
             div = document.createElement('div'),
             css;
        css = '#__scrollToTop{font:12px/1em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;position:fixed;display:none;left:92%;top:80%;text-align:center;z-index:999999; width:74px;height:50px;' +
                                'cursor:pointer;opacity:0.5;padding:2px;}' +
              '#__scrollToTop:hover{opacity:1;}' +
              '#__scrollToTop span.__scroll__arrow{ position:relative;top:20px;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;border-style:solid; border-width:1px;' +
                                                         'border-color:#ccc #ccc #aaa; border-radius:5px;color:#333;font-size:36px;padding:5px 8px 2px;}' +
              ' #__scroll__scroll{height:50px;width:50px;float:left;z-index:100001;position:absolute;} ' +
              '#__scroll__util{font:12px/1em  Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:center;height:44px;width:20px;float:right;position:absolute;left:54px;z-index:100000; ' +
                                 'border-style:solid; border-width:1px;border-color:#ccc #ccc #aaa; border-radius:2px;top:5px;display:none;}' +
              '#__scroll__util span{display:block;height:18px;padding-top:4px;text-align:center;text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #888;font-size:16px;} ' +
              '#__scroll__util span:hover{background-color: #fc9822;}';

        GM_addStyle(css);

        div.id = '__scrollToTop';
        div.title = 'Back To Top';
        div.innerHTML = '<div id="__scroll__scroll">' +
                                                   '<span class="__scroll__arrow">▲</span>' +
                                             '</div>' +
                                             '<div id="__scroll__util">' +
                                                 '<span name="__hide" title="Hide the Button">x</span>' +
                                                 '<span name="__bottom" title="Scroll to the bottom">▼</span>' +
                                             '</div>';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.addEventListener('mousedown', bind(this, 'control'),false);
        div.addEventListener('mouseover', bind(this, 'showUtil'),false);
        div.addEventListener('mouseout', bind(this, 'hideUtil'),false);

        this.util = _('__scroll__util');
        this.pageUtil = _('__scroll__page');
        this.pageHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        return this.imgBtn = div;       

    },
    getImgBtn : function() {
        return this.imgBtn || this.init();
    },
    show : function(elem) {
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    },
    hide : function(elem) {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    },
    showBtn : function() {
        if(this.isBtnShow) return;
        this.isBtnShow = true;
        this.show(this.getImgBtn());
    },
    hideBtn : function() {
        if(!this.isBtnShow) return;
        this.isBtnShow = false;
        this.hide(this.getImgBtn());
    },
    getScrollY : function() {
        //this piece of code is from John Resig's book 'Pro JavaScript Techniques'
        var de = document.documentElement;
        return this.__scrollY = (self.pageYOffset ||
                ( de && de.scrollTop ) ||
                document.body.scrollTop);
    },
    closeBtn : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.hideBtn();
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, false);
    },
    showUtil : function() {        
        this.show(this.util);
    },
    hideUtil : function() {
        this.hide(this.util);
    },
    scroll : function() {
        if(!this.isScrolling) {
           this.isScrolling = true;
        }
        var isStop = false,
             scrollY = this.__scrollY;
        if(this.direction === 'top') {
             isStop = scrollY > 0;
             this.__scrollY = Math.floor(scrollY * this.speed);
        } else {
              isStop = scrollY < this.pageHeight;
              this.__scrollY += Math.ceil((this.pageHeight - scrollY) * (1 - this.speed)) + 10;
        }
        this.isScrolling = isStop;
        window.scrollTo(0, this.__scrollY); 
        isStop ? setTimeout(bind(scroll, 'scroll'), 20) : (this.direction === 'top' && this.hideBtn());
    },
    control : function(e) {
        var t = e.target, name = t.getAttribute('name');
        switch(name) {
            case '__bottom':
                this.scrollToBottom();
                break;
            case '__hide' :
                this.closeBtn(e);
                break;
            default :
                this.scrollToTop();
                break;
        }
    },
    scrollToTop : function() {
        this.direction = 'top';
        this.scroll();
    },
    scrollToBottom : function() {
        this.direction = 'bottom';
        var bodyHeight = global.document.body.scrollHeight,
            documentElementHeight = global.document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        this.pageHeight = Math.max(bodyHeight, documentElementHeight);
        this.scroll();
     }
};

//Autoscroll
(function() {
    var isAutoScroll = false;

    var autoScroll = {
        __autoScrollID : 0,

        isAutoScroll : false,

        defaultSpeed : 1,

        currentSpeed : 1,

        intervalTime : 100,

        reset : function() {
            this.isAutoScroll && (this.currentSpeed = this.defaultSpeed);
        },

        startOrStop : function() {
            var that = this;
            if(that.isAutoScroll) {
                that.isAutoScroll = false;
                clearInterval(that.__autoScrollID);
            } else {
                that.isAutoScroll = true;
                that.__autoScrollID = setInterval(function() {
                    global.scrollBy(0, that.currentSpeed);
                }, that.intervalTime);
            }
        },

        fast : function() {
            this.isAutoScroll && this.currentSpeed <= 10 && this.currentSpeed++;
        },

        slow : function() {
            this.isAutoScroll && this.currentSpeed > 1 && this.currentSpeed--;
        },

        keyControl : function(e) {
            if(e.target != global.document.body && e.target != global.document.documentElement) return false;  // only when the cursor focus on the page rather than the input area can trigger this event.
            var charCode = e.charCode,
                key = this.keyMap[charCode];
            key && this[key]();
        },

        keyMap : {
          '100' : 'slow',        // press 'd', slow the speed of the scroll
          '102' : 'fast',        // press 'f', speed scroll
          '114' : 'reset',       // press 'r', reset the autoscroll's speed
          '115' : 'startOrStop'  //when you click 's' at the first time, the autoscroll is begin, and then you click again, it will stop.
       }
    };
    global.addEventListener('keypress', bind(autoScroll, 'keyControl'), false);
}())
}(window.top))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before `// ==/UserScript==` on a new line:

```
// @grant          GM_addStyle
```

Actually I'm surprised it did work until now because Greasemonkey requires `@grant` for over a year.